# Create fog (smoke) on Unity3D?

Tags: unity, graphic-effects

I'm creating a game where you are inside a boiler room, the problem is I want to create the fog (smoke) to make this more realistic.

Comment: lookup 'unity particle effects'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's particle effects, global fog and custom shader effects such as volumetric fog. A few helpful links are below:

- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/script-GlobalFog.html
- http://www.gamedev.net/blog/633/entry-2254758-volumetric-objects-in-unity/
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-Fog.html
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/17034-fog

Check the Unity Asset Store for alternate fog solutions.